# Utilisation des déterminants dans « portrait de femme »

Tags: articles, déterminants

Lors d'une visite à une exposition. J'ai vu une peinture intitulée « portrait de femme ». Pourquoi pas « portrait d'une femme ». Quelle différence?

Answer (score 3):

- *Portrait de femme* : portrait qui révèle la féminité universelle, ou du moins celle qui inspire l'artiste.
  Ce n'est pas forcément un portrait ressemblant à une personne en particulier, mais celui, anonyme, d'une femme idéalisée.
- *Portrait d'une femme, portraits de femmes<sup>1</sup>* : portrait d'une femme particulière, singulière, qui pourrait avoir un nom, un titre ou une profession, comme on en voit dans les musées.
  Cela peut être une commande faite à l'artiste, un visage qui l'a touché, une particularité, une forme de visage auxquelles il a été sensible.

---

<sup>*1 - Plusieurs portraits de femmes sur la même toile, la même photo...*</sup>

Comment: Connaître les raisons du vote négatif m'aiderait à améliorer ma réponse :) .